Is this WebGPU compute shader badly designed?
I am having unexpected results while comparing a WebGPU compute shader with it's cpu equivalent.
This is a CPU version of a function that does Verlet Integration for simulating particles.
    IntegrateVerlet(dt: number) {
        console.time("verlet");
        const count = this.positions.length / 4;
        /* eslint-disable */
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            const x = this.positions[i * 4 + 0];
            const y = this.positions[i * 4 + 1];
            const z = this.positions[i * 4 + 2];
            const dx = x! - this.prevPositions[i * 4 + 0]!;
            const dy = y! - this.prevPositions[i * 4 + 1]!;
            const dz = z! - this.prevPositions[i * 4 + 2]!;
            const ax = this.forces[i * 4 + 0]! / this.mass;
            const ay = this.forces[i * 4 + 1]! / this.mass;
            const az = this.forces[i * 4 + 2]! / this.mass;

            this.prevPositions[i * 4 + 0] = x!;
            this.prevPositions[i * 4 + 1] = y!;
            this.prevPositions[i * 4 + 2] = z!;

            this.positions[i * 4 + 0] = x! + dx + ax! * dt * dt;
            this.positions[i * 4 + 1] = y! + dy + ay! * dt * dt;
            this.positions[i * 4 + 2] = z! + dz + az! * dt * dt;
        }
        /* eslint-enable */
        console.timeEnd("verlet");
    }

The equivalent Webgpu compute shader could be written as such:
@group(0) @binding(0) var<storage, read_write> positions: array<vec3<f32>>;
@group(0) @binding(1) var<storage, read_write> prevPositions: array<vec3<f32>>;
@group(0) @binding(2) var<storage, read> forces: array<vec3<f32>>;
@group(0) @binding(3) var<uniform> mass: f32;
@group(0) @binding(4) var<uniform> dt: f32;

@compute @workgroup_size(${workgroupSize})
fn main(
        @builtin(workgroup_id) workgroup_id : vec3<u32>,
        @builtin(local_invocation_index) local_invocation_index: u32,
        @builtin(num_workgroups) num_workgroups: vec3<u32>
){
    // workgroup_index is similar to local_invocation_index except for
    // workgroups, not threads inside a workgroup.
    // It is not a builtin so we compute it ourselves.

    let workgroup_index =  
       workgroup_id.x +
       workgroup_id.y * num_workgroups.x +
       workgroup_id.z * num_workgroups.x * num_workgroups.y;

    // global_invocation_index is like local_invocation_index
    // except linear across all invocations across all dispatched
    // workgroups. It is not a builtin so we compute it ourselves.

    let i =
       workgroup_index * ${numThreadsPerWorkgroup} +
       local_invocation_index;

    if (i < arrayLength(&positions)) {
        let dPos = positions[i] - prevPositions[i];
        let a = forces[i] / mass;

        prevPositions[i] = positions[i];

        positions[i] = positions[i] + dPos + a * dt * dt;
    }
}

The particules count is 2000*2000 = 4e6 3d vectors for each buffer.
When comparing both solutions I am surprised to find that the CPU solution is 10 fold faster that the GPU solution. Both functions simulate the system properly.
workgroupSize = 8,8,4
dispatchCount = 25,25,25



avg cpu integration time
avg gpu integration time




16 ms
200 ms



Hardware: 7800x3D + RTX4090, so the GPU raw power should not be the problem.
Software: msedge Version 125.0.2535.92 (Version officielle) (64 bits)
What should I change to get better GPU speed than the CPU? Where is the bottleneck?
